# Detect iPad (or iOS) for only a single href change

Tags: javascript, html, ios, href, detect

I've searched through lots of posts and found quite a few scripts that will redirect iOS devices to a different page.  But I don't want to change the whole page, just one link.

The whole site (www.example.com) works fine for iOS devices and includes one link to a flash based application page (on a different host - app.example.com).  This particular application has an iOS version for use on iPads.  When the link is clicked, I simply want computer users to be sent to the flash app page, and iPad users to be sent to a page (on www.) that tells them about the iOS app.

I envision something like:

Use an iOS detection script in the head to set 'isiPad' variable to 'true' if the user is on iPad.  Then in the body something that would function like:

if 'isiPad'=true, then

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/useiOSapp.html"> Run the App </a>
```

otherwise

```
<a href="http://app.example.com/flash-app-page.html">Run the App</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

### Html

```
<a id="myLink" href="">Run App</a>
```

### Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    var agentID = deviceAgent.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad)/);
    if (agentID) {
        $('#myLink').attr('href', 'http://example.com/useiOSapp.html');
    }else
     { 
         $('#myLink').attr('href', 'http://example.com/flash-app-page.html');
     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  This makes sense to me and was along the lines of what I was thinking.  I really appreciate the exact code!

Comment: If this answered your question you should select it as the answer for people who have this issue in the future.  Glad it helped you out.

Answer (score 1):

You could run this through htaccess and rewrite the URL.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*iPad.*$
RewriteRule ^http://example.com/flash-app-page.html$ http://example.com/useiOSapp.html [R=301]
```

Alternatively, you can declare this as a js var:

```
var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;
```

then on ready call a function that rewrites the url...
jquery version:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(isiPad)
    {
        $('#link_id').attr('href', 'http://example.com/useiOSapp.html');
    }
});
```

(assumes you also give your link an ID of "link_id")

Comment: I had ignored all the htaccess posts because I thought htaccess was only good for 'whole page' changes.  I didn't know it could be used for single things.  Thanks for teaching me something new!

Comment: I think I may have not included enough information and left out an important item.  I just got around to trying the htaccess method and can't make it work.  I like this option because it will work on all pages in the directory.  For testing purposes, I commented out the RewriteCond.  Rewriting is working if I rewrite one local page to another.  But here's where I maybe didn't give enough info.  The flash app is on a different host.  I've updated the original post to show the difference.  Is it possible to rewrite an external address?  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Well, I'll respond with my own work around.  I added an additional page that is simply a redirect page to the external Flash app.  I then point my regular users to that local redirect page, and using htaccess, rewrite iPad users to the useIOSapp.html page.